# Python Pandas Dataframe Self Referencing Variable as in Function nz(x,y) to python pandas data frame logic

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

In my coding, i experience a problem converting a non-python function to a python function for a self-referencing variable.

A Brief about it :A self-referencing variable is a variable that refers to its past values on previous bars from the right side of its declaration.

More on this in this link under self-referencingvariable https://blog.tradingview.com/en/tradingview-pine-script-new-features-223/

However, on the first bar there is no srv value, so the value srv[1](https://blog.tradingview.com/en/tradingview-pine-script-new-features-223/) will be missing on the first bar (to be more precise it will be NaN – Not-A-Number). To change the NaN values it’s possible to turn call to previous values into a nz function

nz
Replaces NaN values with zeros (or given value) in a series.

Input:

```
             close    smooth
date        
01-07-02    5.4127  0.416113
02-07-02    5.4438  0.416113
03-07-02    5.4661  0.416114
04-07-02    5.5283  0.416115
05-07-02    5.5905  0.416116
08-07-02    5.6255  0.416116
09-07-02    5.6167  0.416116
10-07-02    5.2222  0.41611
11-07-02    5.1863  0.416109
12-07-02    5.3194  0.416111
15-07-02    5.333   0.416111
16-07-02    5.3155  0.416111
17-07-02    5.0445  0.416107
18-07-02    5.0804  0.416107
19-07-02    5.1513  0.416109
22-07-02    4.9735  0.416106
23-07-02    5.0619  0.416107
24-07-02    5.0619  0.416107
25-07-02    4.8492  0.416104
```

I want to convert this below function to python code

```
kama=nz(kama[1], close)+smooth*(close-nz(kama[1], close))
```

Let us see case by case

kama is the output shall be in the format of dataframe stockdata['kama']

nz(kama[1](https://blog.tradingview.com/en/tradingview-pine-script-new-features-223/), close)

here first time kama will be NaN hence close shall be assigned and second iteration onwards previous kama value to be considered for calculation
 So with the above-given input the first kama value will be 5.4127(first close value) afterwards previous kama value.

smooth and close values are already available ,how this function can be converted as python code for nonzero calculation.

The final out should be in the form of 
kama=nz(kama[1](https://blog.tradingview.com/en/tradingview-pine-script-new-features-223/), close)+smooth*(close-nz(kama[1](https://blog.tradingview.com/en/tradingview-pine-script-new-features-223/), close))

The output expected

```
             close    smooth    kama
date        
01-07-02    5.4127  0.416113    prev.close+smooth*(prev.close-close)
02-07-02    5.4438  0.416113    prevourKama+smooth*(prev.row.close-previouskama)
03-07-02    5.4661  0.416114    "
04-07-02    5.5283  0.416115    "
05-07-02    5.5905  0.416116    "
08-07-02    5.6255  0.416116
09-07-02    5.6167  0.416116
10-07-02    5.2222  0.41611
11-07-02    5.1863  0.416109
12-07-02    5.3194  0.416111
15-07-02    5.333   0.416111
16-07-02    5.3155  0.416111
17-07-02    5.0445  0.416107
18-07-02    5.0804  0.416107
19-07-02    5.1513  0.416109
22-07-02    4.9735  0.416106
23-07-02    5.0619  0.416107
24-07-02    5.0619  0.416107
25-07-02    4.8492  0.416104
```

Here ultimately for the first row no kama value will be available as we check previous value ,in order avoid the Nan value the close value is replaced.If in any of the row the kama is zero then it has to be replaced with current row close value.